# How do I inspect this element or find this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

On this page: http://www.sysaway.com/account/login if you type in some garbage into the email address and click 'Login' you see the following message:

[image: login error needing translated]

I'm trying to find the code responsible for that little popup window with the exclamation mark and the error message (I need to translate it using Javascript).

I can't right click it and do inspect element in Chrome - it doesn't let me.

I've tried CTRL+SHIFT+I then looking at sources and searching through all of them for the code.

I've also tried the Chrome extension Visual Event - it shows an event on the Sign In button but nothing useful (just a blur event).

How do I find this code? There must be a way I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just plain HTML. Specifically the [form validation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#client-side-form-validation) functionality introduced in HTML 5.

```
<input name=whatever type=email required>
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense now. So these will be auto-translated by the browser depending on the users language settings. Damn I was banging my head against a brick wall trying to figure out what kind of trickery had been employed to prevent me inspecting the element of the popover...

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the standard message chrome will display on an email type input

```
<input type="email" required>
```

[W3Schools Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_email)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problem inspecting element

It should be the effect of

```
<input type="email">
```

not javascript

Comment: I was trying to find the element of the popup validation message so I could translate it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Its HTML default functionality to validate email ,when you use type="email" in your html.

```
<input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="customer_email" placeholder="Email" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autofocus="">
```